# Moodle-Enrolement-Course-Information via SQL-Statement

Tags: mysql, moodle

How can i find out the role which a user have in a Moodle_Course?
RoleID=1, 2, 3, 4, 5... ??
Also,Is he teacher or is he student?

etc.

Im locking for the SQL-Statement

Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, simply change the where clause to match your own.

```sh
SELECT c.fullname as 'Course Name', concat(u.firstname ,' ',u.lastname) AS 'User Name', 
r.shortname as 'Role Name', r.id as 'Role ID'
FROM mdl_role_assignments AS ra
JOIN mdl_role AS r ON r.id = ra.roleid
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON (ctx.id = ra.contextid AND ctx.contextlevel = 50)
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON ctx.instanceid = c.id
WHERE u.id = 3 # For specific user ID
AND c.id = 2 # For specific course, remove it, if you need to see all courses.
```